# insert-image doesn't work in the org code block

Tags: org-mode, images

I have an org file, which contains the following text:

```
#+begin_src elisp
(insert-image
     (create-image "/home/searene/Pictures/Selection_007.png"))
#+end_src
```

When I press `C-c C-c` to evaluate the code, I want the image to insert in the current file, but that's not the result. The result is just a `t`, as follows:

```
#+begin_src elisp
 (insert-image
     (create-image "/home/searene/Pictures/Selection_007.png"))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: t
```

Why? How can I insert the image by executing the code?

Comment: It works for me.  Does it work if you place the cursor on the line after the `#+end_src` of the code block and do `C-c C-c`? What about  if you copy the code to the `*scratch*` buffer, and press `C-j` with the cursor after the closing paren? If `C-j` does not work, try `C-x C-e` at the same place.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @NickD Thanks, strangely it works in the scratch buffer by evaluating it with `C-x C-e`, but it doesn't work in the org file, whether using `C-c C-c` or `C-c C-e`, both of the results are `t`. By the way, I'm using Spacemacs, not sure if it matters.

Comment: @Searene I get the same results as you, both in standard Spacemacs and pure vanilla using `emacs -Q`.  I get the `t` result also in an `ielm` buffer.  I don't understand why you're creating an image resource rather than just referring to the file path with `[[/my/path/img.png]]`